# Blit Bug: Not Showing Up

Tags: python, pygame, blit

I'm trying to create a Hangman-ish game, and I've noticed something weird going on with the `screen.blit`.

In the word 'CANADA', there are three A's. I have successfully created a list with all the letters of the alphabet, and when I click on 'C' it actually transfers the 'C' to it's designated place. However, when you click the 'A', only the first 'A' shows up.

Here is my code:

```
def canada1():
    name = ""
    main_font = "brain flower euro.ttf"
    font1 = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 50)
    font2 = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)

    country = list('canada')
    flag = 'canada_flag.jpeg'
    black = 0, 0, 0
    red = 255, 0, 0
    white = 255, 255, 255
    flag1 = pygame.image.load(flag).convert()

    aPosition = 285, 325
    bPosition = 335, 325
    cPosition = 385, 325
    dPosition = 435, 325
    ePosition = 485, 325
    fPosition = 535, 325
    gPosition = 585, 325
    hPosition = 635, 325
    iPosition = 685, 325
    jPosition = 285, 375
    kPosition = 335, 375
    lPosition = 385, 375
    mPosition = 435, 375
    nPosition = 485, 375
    oPosition = 535, 375
    pPosition = 585, 375
    qPosition = 635, 375
    rPosition = 685, 375
    sPosition = 285, 425
    tPosition = 335, 425
    uPosition = 385, 425
    vPosition = 435, 425
    wPosition = 485, 425
    xPosition = 535, 425
    yPosition = 585, 425
    zPosition = 635, 425

    letters = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza')
    a = font2.render(str(letters[0]), True, (black))
    b = font2.render(str(letters[1]), True, (black))
    c = font2.render(str(letters[2]), True, (black))
    d = font2.render(str(letters[3]), True, (black))
    e = font2.render(str(letters[4]), True, (black))
    f = font2.render(str(letters[5]), True, (black))
    g = font2.render(str(letters[6]), True, (black))
    h = font2.render(str(letters[7]), True, (black))
    i = font2.render(str(letters[8]), True, (black))
    j = font2.render(str(letters[9]), True, (black))
    k = font2.render(str(letters[10]), True, (black))
    l = font2.render(str(letters[11]), True, (black))
    m = font2.render(str(letters[12]), True, (black))
    n = font2.render(str(letters[13]), True, (black))
    o = font2.render(str(letters[14]), True, (black))
    p = font2.render(str(letters[15]), True, (black))
    q = font2.render(str(letters[16]), True, (black))
    r = font2.render(str(letters[17]), True, (black))
    s = font2.render(str(letters[18]), True, (black))
    t = font2.render(str(letters[19]), True, (black))
    u = font2.render(str(letters[20]), True, (black))
    v = font2.render(str(letters[21]), True, (black))
    w = font2.render(str(letters[22]), True, (black))
    x = font2.render(str(letters[23]), True, (black))
    y = font2.render(str(letters[24]), True, (black))
    z = font2.render(str(letters[25]), True, (black))

    a1 = a.get_rect()
    b1 = b.get_rect()
    c1 = c.get_rect()
    d1 = d.get_rect()
    e1 = e.get_rect()
    f1 = f.get_rect()
    g1 = g.get_rect()
    h1 = h.get_rect()
    i1 = i.get_rect()
    j1 = j.get_rect()
    k1 = k.get_rect()
    l1 = l.get_rect()
    m1 = m.get_rect()
    n1 = n.get_rect()
    o1 = o.get_rect()
    p1 = p.get_rect()
    q1 = q.get_rect()
    r1 = r.get_rect()
    s1 = s.get_rect()
    t1 = t.get_rect()
    u1 = u.get_rect()
    v1 = v.get_rect()
    w1 = w.get_rect()
    x1 = x.get_rect()
    y1 = y.get_rect()
    z1 = z.get_rect()

    a1.x, a1.y = 285, 325
    b1.x, b1.y = 335, 325
    c1.x, c1.y = 385, 325
    d1.x, d1.y = 435, 325
    e1.x, e1.y = 485, 325
    f1.x, f1.y = 535, 325
    g1.x, g1.y = 585, 325
    h1.x, h1.y = 635, 325
    i1.x, i1.y = 685, 325
    j1.x, j1.y = 285, 375
    k1.x, k1.y = 335, 375
    l1.x, l1.y = 385, 375
    m1.x, m1.y = 435, 375
    n1.x, n1.y = 485, 375
    o1.x, o1.y = 535, 375
    p1.x, p1.y = 585, 375
    q1.x, q1.y = 635, 375
    r1.x, r1.y = 685, 375
    s1.x, s1.y = 285, 425
    t1.x, t1.y = 335, 425
    u1.x, u1.y = 385, 425
    v1.x, v1.y = 435, 425
    w1.x, w1.y = 485, 425
    x1.x, x1.y = 535, 425
    y1.x, y1.y = 585, 425
    z1.x, z1.y = 635, 425

    while True:
        for evt in pygame.event.get():
            if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
                if evt.unicode.isalpha():
                    name += evt.unicode
                elif evt.key == K_SPACE:
                    name += " "
                elif evt.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                    name = name[:-1]
            elif evt.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if evt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if a1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    letter = letters[0]
                    check = country.count(letter)
                    if check >= 1:
                        if letter == letters[0]:
                            aPosition = 375, 235
                            screen.blit(a, (425, 235))
                            screen.blit(a, (475, 235))
                            a1.x, a1.y = -500, -500
                        elif letter == letters[2]:
                            cPosition = 300, 235
                            c1.x, c1.y = -500, -500
                        elif letter == letters[13]:
                            nPosition = 350, 235
                            n1.x, n1.y = -500, -500
                        elif letter == letters[3]:
                            dPosition = 400, 235
                            d1.x, d2.y = -500, -500
                    else:
                        a2 = font.render(str(letters[0]), True, (red))
                        screen.blit(a2, (cPosition))
                        time.sleep(1)
                        aPosition = -500, -500
                        a1.x, a1.y = -500, -500
                elif b1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    letter = letters[1]
                    check = country.count(letter)
                    if check >= 1:
                        if letter == letters[0]:
                            aPosition = 325, 235
                            a3 = screen.blit((a), (375, 235))
                            a4 = screen.blit((a), (425, 235))
                            a1.x, a1.y = -500, -500
                        elif letter == letters[2]:
                            cPosition = 300, 235
                            c1.x, c1.y = -500, -500
                        elif letter == letters[13]:
                            nPosition = 350, 235
                            n1.x, n1.y = -500, -500
                        elif letter == letters[3]:
                            dPosition = 400, 235
                            d1.x, d2.y = -500, -500
                    else:
                        b2 = font.render(str(letters[1]), True, (red))
                        screen.blit(b2, (485, 325))
                        time.sleep(1)
                        bPosition = -500, -500
                        b1.x, b1.y = -500, -500
                elif c1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    letter = letters[2]
                    check = country.count(letter)
                    if check >= 1:
                        if letter == letters[0]:
                            aPosition = 325, 235
                            screen.blit((a), (375, 235))
                            screen.blit((a), (425, 235))
                            a1.x, a1.y = -500, -500
                        elif letter == letters[2]:
                            cPosition = 300, 235
                            c1.x, c1.y = -500, -1
                        elif letter == letters[13]:
                            nPosition = 350, 235
                            n1.x, n1.y = -1, -1
                        elif letter == letters[3]:
                            dPosition = 400, 235
                            d1.x, d2.y = -1, -1
                    else:
                        c2 = font.render(str(letters[2]), True, (red))
                        screen.blit(c2, (cPosition))
                        time.sleep(1)
                        cPosition = -1, -1
                        c1.x, c1.y = -1, -1


        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

        screen.blit(flag1, (300, 10))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (275, 0), (275, 300), (6))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (715, 0), (715, 300), (6))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (0, 300), (1000, 300), (6))

        block = font1.render(name, True, black)
        rect = block.get_rect(center = (500, 600))
        screen.blit(block, rect)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (375, 550, 250, 100), (2))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (775, 250), (775, 50), (4))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (750, 250), (800, 250), (4))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (775, 50), (925, 50), (4))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (925, 50), (925, 175), (4))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (925, 100), 30, (0))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (925, 125), (925, 200), (4))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (885, 160), (965, 160), (4))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (925, 200), (900, 225), (4))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (925, 200), (950, 225), (4))

        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (295, 275), (320, 275), (5))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (370, 275), (395, 275), (5))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (445, 275), (470, 275), (5))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (520, 275), (545, 275), (5))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (595, 275), (620, 275), (5))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (670, 275), (695, 275), (5))

        a2 = screen.blit((a), (aPosition))
        b2 = screen.blit((b), (bPosition))
        c2 = screen.blit((c), (cPosition))
        d2 = screen.blit((d), (dPosition))
        e2 = screen.blit((e), (ePosition))
        f2 = screen.blit((f), (fPosition))
        g2 = screen.blit((g), (gPosition))
        h2 = screen.blit((h), (hPosition))
        i2 = screen.blit((i), (iPosition))
        j2 = screen.blit((j), (jPosition))
        k2 = screen.blit((k), (kPosition))
        l2 = screen.blit((l), (lPosition))
        m2 = screen.blit((m), (mPosition))
        n2 = screen.blit((n), (nPosition))
        o2 = screen.blit((o), (oPosition))
        p2 = screen.blit((p), (pPosition))
        q2 = screen.blit((q), (qPosition))
        r2 = screen.blit((r), (rPosition))
        s2 = screen.blit((s), (sPosition))
        t2 = screen.blit((t), (tPosition))
        u2 = screen.blit((u), (uPosition))
        v2 = screen.blit((v), (vPosition))
        w2 = screen.blit((w), (wPosition))
        x2 = screen.blit((x), (xPosition))
        y2 = screen.blit((y), (yPosition))
        z2 = screen.blit((z), (zPosition))

        if a1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            a2 = font.render(str(letters[0]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(a2, (285, 325))
        elif b1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            b2 = font.render(str(letters[1]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(b2, (335, 325))
        elif c1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            c2 = font.render(str(letters[2]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(c2, (385, 325))
        elif d1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            d2 = font.render(str(letters[3]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(d2, (435, 325))
        elif e1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            e2 = font.render(str(letters[4]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(e2, (485, 325))
        elif f1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            f2 = font.render(str(letters[5]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(f2, (535, 325))
        elif g1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            g2 = font.render(str(letters[6]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(g2, (585, 325))
        elif h1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            h2 = font.render(str(letters[7]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(h2, (635, 325))
        elif i1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            i2 = font.render(str(letters[8]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(i2, (685, 325))
        elif j1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            j2 = font.render(str(letters[9]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(j2, (285, 375))
        elif k1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            k2 = font.render(str(letters[10]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(k2, (335, 375))
        elif l1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            l2 = font.render(str(letters[11]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(l2, (385, 375))
        elif m1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            m2 = font.render(str(letters[12]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(m2, (435, 375))
        elif n1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            n2 = font.render(str(letters[13]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(n2, (485, 375))
        elif o1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            o2 = font.render(str(letters[14]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(o2, (535, 375))
        elif p1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            p2 = font.render(str(letters[15]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(p2, (585, 375))
        elif q1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            q2 = font.render(str(letters[16]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(q2, (635, 375))
        elif r1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            r2 = font.render(str(letters[17]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(r2, (685, 375))
        elif s1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            s2 = font.render(str(letters[18]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(s2, (285, 425))
        elif t1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            t2 = font.render(str(letters[19]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(t2, (335, 425))
        elif u1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            u2 = font.render(str(letters[20]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(u2, (385, 425))
        elif v1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            v2 = font.render(str(letters[21]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(v2, (435, 425))
        elif w1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            w2 = font.render(str(letters[22]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(w2, (485, 425))
        elif x1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            x2 = font.render(str(letters[23]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(x2, (535, 425))
        elif y1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            y2 = font.render(str(letters[24]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(y2, (585, 425))
        elif z1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            font = pygame.font.Font((main_font), 40)
            z2 = font.render(str(letters[25]), True, (red))
            screen.blit(z2, (635, 425))

        if name == country:
            return
        pygame.display.update()
```

Absolutely everything else works, but the 'A' problem.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PyGame, but looking at your program, it looks like this is what is happening:

1. Check for mouse events
2. Draw any correctly selected letters
3. Clear the screen (`screen.fill((255, 255, 255))`)
4. Redraw everything (only includes original copies of letters)

So you can see that the 'A's will be drawn momentarily but then erased in parts 3 and 4. If you need to clear the screen in every iteration, then you will need to keep track of objects to keep drawing, by adding them to a list, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I screen.blitted something a separate A, with different positions. It's original position was outside the screen, and popped into the proper line of code when the 'A' was pressed.